# Is there any way to add new field to Kentico Kontent content item Meta tab

Tags: kentico, kentico-kontent

So what I am basically trying to do, is to have the ability to add custom field(e.g. Secondary URL) to Content item Meta Tab, so that the user can set it manually on demand. Reading docs did not bring any result
On the attached screenshot, you can see Path, Navigation title fields, so I need to add additional one

[image: Meta tab]

Answer (score 0):

to be able to modify the content type - in your case adding a new field - it is required to have [the proper permissions via assigned roles](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/manage-kontent/roles-and-workflow/configure-and-assign-roles). More specifically, you need to have permission to [modify content](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/manage-kontent/roles-and-workflow/permission-reference#a-content-model).

Content modeling could be done via UI - see [Content modeling tutorial](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/manage-kontent/content-modeling/), in your case it is [Adding an element into a content group "Metadata"](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/manage-kontent/content-modeling/organize-elements-with-content-groups#a-adding-elements-to-content-groups). You also can use [REST Management API](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/management-api-v2#operation/modify-a-content-type) for that.